# How to inject Spring boot Environment bean to Custom Spring xml bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-context

I created a bean using spring boot @Configuration class annotation like below

```
@Configuration
public class CustomConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MyEnvironmentProcessor myEnvironmentProcessor(Environment env) {
        return new MyEnvironmentProcessor(env);
    }
}
```

In one of the application I am using Spring XML to create the bean then loading them using Spring boot there I am trying to create the same bean in XML but it was not working, I tried below

```
<bean id="myEnvironmentProcessor " class="com.example.MyEnvironmentProcessor">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.core.env.Environment"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

How to create an equivalent Java based bean in Spring XML?

Spring version: 5.2.4.RELEASE
Spring boot version: 2.2.5.RELEASE

Comment: You shouldn't need anything besides `<bean class="com.example.MyEnvironmentProcessor" />`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- No it shouldn't work. I require an equivalent of java version in XML. Your recommendation will throw ***No default constructor found*** exception because custom class expect ***Environment*** as argument.

Comment: Then you need to specify your Spring version, since you seem to be using a very old one (older than 4.3).

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I am using newer version of both Spring 5.2.4 and Spring boot 2.2.5

Comment: Since 4.3 Spring has been perfectly happy to use a singleton constructor with injected dependencies _even without_ `@Autowired`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the environment by referencing its ID, which is `environment`, instead of its class:

```xml
<bean id="myEnvironmentProcessor" class="com.example.MyEnvironmentProcessor">
    <constructor-arg ref="environment"/>
</bean>
```

```java
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

public class MyEnvironmentProcessor {
    private Environment environment;

    public MyEnvironmentProcessor(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }
}
```

By the way, your bean definition has a space character in the ID;  `"myEnvironmentProcessor "`